# How to databind to a Gridview where column values should appear in sub rows within a main row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

Please can anyone suggest a way to databind a database table to a gridview but in a specific layout where column values should appear in sub rows within a main row, like wise all rows from the database table should list down inside that Gridview.I know the normal way of databinding to a gridview Where it display row data(From Database Table) as columns, but what I want is like below
[image]

Comment: I would use repeater where I can put the first field  in a <tr> and other fields in another tr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gridview is not suitable for this type of format.

If you are okay with repeater, you can do something like this:

And here's a link to MSDN: [Repeater Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx).

**UPDATE:** If you want to post each answer selection, you can use option button and group them. You can use questionid as a part of group name and in the code get the question id. Your markup may look like below:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2"></th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuestionId") %> </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Question") %> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer1") %>' 
                                OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" GroupName='<%# Eval("QuestionId","Grp_{0}") %>' TextAlign="Left" />                       
                        </td>
                        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer2") %>'  
                            OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton2_CheckedChanged" GroupName='<%# Eval("QuestionId","Grp_{0}") %>' TextAlign="Left" />                        
                        </td>
                        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer3") %>'  
                            OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton3_CheckedChanged" GroupName='<%# Eval("QuestionId","Grp_{0}") %>' TextAlign="Left" />
                        </td>
                        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer4") %>'  
                            OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton4_CheckedChanged" GroupName='<%# Eval("QuestionId","Grp_{0}") %>' TextAlign="Left" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And in the code:

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string grpId = ((RadioButton)sender).GroupName;
    int questionId = 0;

    int.TryParse(grpId.Split('_')[1].ToString(), out questionId);

    //Use questionId
}
```

Comment: Afzalulh, need a small favor, I successfully did the above part, in addition to that, i have added asp:RadioButtons infront of every answer, so now onCheckedChange it will call a code behind method "check_Answer" but i need to pass the value of <td> where it contains the question ID, to code behind, please can you suggest me a way, Sorry to disturb you again..

Comment: I have updated my answer. I am assuming that you want to post each answer.